# How can I make a thin border around text

Tags: framed, border, fbox

I am using

```
\noindent\fbox{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
        text
    }%
}
```

For a box around text like this:[image]

I want to make a morest thin border.

I don't know how.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Are you meaning a less thick line? It is `\setlength{\fboxrule}{some length}`. The default in standard classes is `0.4pt`.

Comment: You can go _really_ thin with `\setlength{\fboxrule}{1sp}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thickness of the rule is determined by the length `\fboxrule`. For a thinner rule, set it to a small value

```
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
```

Or as you think best. You will have to experiment to find a suitable thickness. The default is 0.4pt.